# Rigorous justification for firewalls?

Tags: black-holes, resource-recommendations, soft-question, research-level, black-hole-firewall

[Jerusalem lectures by Harlow](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1231) does a good job in giving a heuristic derivation of firewalls. But the details are not done and no reference is given except for a "related" calculation by [Giddings](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0605196). Harlow says

> "I will not describe this in detail here, but one can see without too much difficulty that even fairly mild decorrelation already leads to O(1) probability that the detector clicks as it crosses the horizon.".

Where can I find a derivation of these facts without going to lattice field theory? What is the rigorous (physicist level) justification for firewalls? I suppose there *are* calculations regarding existence of firewalls but hard to find because the name "firewalls" is relatively new, but the concept might be not.

Comment: Whether there are firewalls in evolved black holes is still an open question, so no “rigorous” calculations exist. There are only arguments based on our beliefs about how QG works.

Comment: I know that it is still an open question _in black holes_, but when we are arguing for firewalls as an step in deriving the AMPS paradox, why do we think that there is a firewall in the first place if it is not rigorously justified? I am not asking whether the firewall exist or not i.e. whether the AMPSS and allied arguments are rigorously valid or not.  I am asking a question about entanglement structure of QFTs and equivalence principle and not particularly about the AMPSS paradox resolution which is an open question. I ask as it was indicated in the lecture that there _are_ justifications.